# How do I save a multi dimensional array to Realm using Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

this is my first time posting a question so forgive me if I do something wrong.

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain a way of saving a multi dimensional array in Realm using swift. I've looked at a lot of forums and unfortunately I'm stumped. I've been trying to solve this for a week now.

I have an array called sequence made up of Int arrays

`var sequence = [[0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [4, 5, 1]]`

I need to save this in realm but I also need to be able to add and remove arrays from within the array when i call a method.

If somebody has a solution I'd be extremely gratefull.

Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody have a solution?